# insert results of join in SQL server 2005

Tags: sql-server, inner-join, full-outer-join

I have two tables with more than 800 rows in each.Table names are 'education' and 'sanitation'.The column name 'ID' is common in both the tables.Now i want to join these both tables as full outer join and i want to save the results of this table as a new table.I can join it very easily,But how to save those data's as a new table.Please help Me.

```
select * into bc  from education e join sanitation s on e.id=s.id
```

I have around 30 columns in each table.So i can not explicitly create table schema for a new table.

I want all the columns from both tables.I have 20 tables with each 800 rows.From this 20 tables i want to make one master table taking 'ID' as primary key in all.

Comment: there is an example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) see "Creating a table by specifying columns from multiple sources"

Comment: you could use `sys.columns` to construct (then execute) a dynamic query if you want to sidestep defining all columns and `*`

Comment: Thank You YS.Please Send me some link with examples.

Comment: I want all the columns from both tables.I have 20 tables with each 800 rows.From this 20 tables i want to make one master table having 'ID' is common in all.

Answer (score 1):

**Sample Code:**

Table one:

```
create table dummy1(
id int , fname varchar(50)
)
insert into dummy1 (id,fname) values (1,'aaa')
insert into dummy1 (id,fname) values (2,'bbb')
insert into dummy1 (id,fname) values (3,'ccc')
insert into dummy1 (id,fname) values (3,'ccc')
```

Table Two

```
create table dummy2(
id int , lname varchar(50)
)
insert into dummy2 (id,lname)  values (1,'abc')
insert into dummy2 (id,lname)  values (2,'pqr')
insert into dummy2 (id,lname)  values (3,'mno')
```

Now Create new table 3

```
create table dummy3(
id int , fname varchar(50),lname varchar(50)
)
```

Insert Query for table 3 look like

```
insert into dummy3 (id,fname,lname)
 (select a.id,a.fname,b.lname from dummy1  a inner join dummy2 b on a.id=b.id)
```

Table 3 will contain table1, table2 data

Answer (score 0):

Follow below:

```
SELECT  t1.Column1, t2.Columnx
INTO    DestinationTable
FROm    education  t1
        INNER JOIN sanitation  t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

**EDIT**:

**SELECT *** will not work for you because you have a column ID which exists in both the tables. So the above solution will work you.

**EDIT:**

1- You can temporarily rename the Id column in one table, then try

```
2-  SELECT   *
    INTO    DestinationTable
    FROm    education  t1
            INNER JOIN sanitation  t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

3- Revert the column name back to Id.

Comment: OP editted his question - "I have around 30 columns in each table.So i can not explicitly create table schema for a new table."